# HP Probook4420s WiFi not working

Tags: wireless-networking

So I have a laptop (Hp Probook 4420s) where the WiFi button isn't working. Also when I press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Mobility Center, the WiFi button is greyed out.

This means I can't use WiFi. I have no idea why this happened. When the WiFi didn't work I reinstalled Windows 7 but it didn't fix it.

Could you help me please?

Comment: I cannot comment hence I am writing an answer. Try downloading and installing the wifi driver from the hp website, that might help.

Comment: type `windows+r` and run, `compmgmt.msc`. Next click on `Device manager`. Do you see any devices with a yellow exclamation mark?

Comment: Register, use the contact us button, and ask for accounts to be merged.

Comment: Have you checked the BIOS to see if there is options to disable/enable wifi there?

Comment: Did you install the Wifi driver?